# XML to JSON in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

Is there a library in Flex/ActionScript to convert XML to JSON, similar to the json gem in the Ruby world?

Answer (score 3):

I think [as3corelib](http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/) has that functionality.

Comment: You can convert xml to an object easily and then encode it to json using as3corelib then.